# Zumero: Can I use a different database in the Cloud (big), then on the device (small) or only an exact replicate?

Tags: zumero

I'm at the point of giving Zumero a shot. I have downloaded the Zumero Client SDK for the cloud and was going through the getting started and zumero_core.
I am wondering if my impression of Zumero is correct and if it is not recommended to use Zumero in my use case.

My impression: Zumero makes an exact replicate of the SQLite database on the Client in the Cloud. It keeps these two in sync. (with zumero_sync())

My Use-Case: Reservation app, so there is one big database and every consumer will only have her records locally. So a small part of the big database, the consumer can't have access to the other data. So I wanted to provide certain columns and rows with sync capability.

Is it true that Zumero replicates and by this can not help me to achieve my use case, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Zumero-in-the-cloud, no, you can't directly do that. You'd need to create separate DBFiles per customer.

[Zumero for SQL Server](http://zumero.com/dev-center/zss) *does* allow [server-side filtering](http://zumero.com/docs/zumero_for_sql_server_manager.html#filters), so you could filter per-user, choose a subset of columns that the user can see, etc.

Comment: Thanks foor the fast response! Is it possible (and not a hassle) to have one big DBFile which interacts with these small DBFiles so they keep in sync (on the cloud side)?

Comment: In ZSS, yes. In the current cloud setup, no -- synching is purely at the one-to-one DBFile level.

Comment: perfectly clear know! It seems from your answers and http://zumero.com/news/ that ZSS is actively being developed and has and will have more functionaly than the cloud. Or are you planning to improve and match the cloud with ZSS? Furthermore on http://zumero.com/pricing/ the Cloud is advised when starting from scratch. Will this also be the case for our use-case in the future, or do you advise ZSS? (multiple questions and maybe difficult to answer, sorry :)

Comment: Those are more "email sales@zumero.com" questions than technical ones. :-)